# SQL Server CPU utilization vs Long running queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, cpu, database-administration, long-running-processes

Correct me if Im wrong,

According to SQL server if a query took more CPU time then it consider as a High cpu consuming query.

My Question - `Is all Long running queries are high CPU consuming queries?`

Or give me a shot description to identify the difference between them.

Comment: Some long-running queries are CPU-bound.  Two other possibilities are IO-bound or "deadlocked".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Question - Is all Long running queries are high CPU consuming
>   queries?

Absolutely not.  Queries that are not actively executing (consuming CPU) are waiting on a resource or an operation to complete. This is why analyzing wait statistics is a common performance tuning methodology, which is summarized in [Brent Ozar's article](https://www.brentozar.com/responder/triage-wait-stats-in-sql-server/).

Common scenarios where long-running queries are not CPU-bound include blocking,
disk I/O and network waits, memory grant waits, unproductive work like [hash and sort spills](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/tempdb-spills/).

Query and index tuning can help mitigate the above problems but performance will ultimately be limited by hardware capabilities.  The server must be sized for the expected workload.